# how to keep jar dependancy while checking in code

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I have a scala project built with dependancy on a locally built jar file (java code). Once I need to check in my scala code into a different environment for building and deployment, what's the best way to keep my jar file in the dependancy? 
I know that if I use the sbt dependancy from online modules, I don't need to worry, it will download the version and build, but what if I want to use my own jar file for this purpose?

This is in OSX, and code will be checked into linux machines, I am using intellij and sbt to manage my scala project. I also used intellij to build my external java lib into jar file and added dependancy of this specific path.

I hope there should be some generic solution, but I am new in JAVA and SBT

Comment: While it is not recommended, you can still commit your jar into your repository.

Comment: but how do you build your task with sbt?

Comment: You can store your jar in s3 or on ftp?

Comment: Maybe [sbt-s3-resolver](https://github.com/ohnosequences/sbt-s3-resolver) would work for you?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I will definitely check out s3 :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. Add the jar files under the lib directory right under the project will solve the problem. SBT will pick it up automatically and you can certainly check in the jar files like source code.